# What would happen to the surface of the earth after a GRB hit?

Tags: science-based

I was told to shorten my question to a number of different questions altogether.

Let's say that WR-38 blasted Earth, what would happen to the surface of earth?

More specifically, how would the changes to the ozone layer effect the surface?  Perhaps this could cause smog on the surface, or maybe it leaves an enormous pit from the radiation burst.  How would the surface differ after the shock of a GRB?

What would the surface of earth look like if a GRB ruined the ozone layer?  In other words, what are implications for surface life post GRB hit?

Comment: Some other questions on this site sort of touch upon this topic: [How close must a supernova be to severely harm the Earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3615), [Could (life on) Earth Survive a Gamma Ray Burst?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/127050), [How much time would you have to build cities underground after a gamma ray burst?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/99079), [Is it possible for coronal mass ejections or perhaps a gamma ray burst to cause firestorms on an earth-like planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/42678)

Comment: This isn't ready to be reopened. Think of it this way, you're asking us to predict what will happen to the surface of *the entire earth.* Every mountain, city, desert, plain, ocean, lake, river, person, animal, insect... You've asked a vague question, here's a vague answer: bad things.  Please remember, the SE model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. Asking what will happen to the surface is not specific. Even asking what would happen to the atmosphere (just the gas, nothing else) isn't specific. Asking what would happen to the atmo on the impact side *might* be specific enough.

Comment: In addition to other comments, why WR-38? Seems like a pretty unremarkable gamma ray source. Perhaps provide some background explaining the magnitude of energy you want to hit the Earth with?

Comment: Nate, being asked to "shorten" your query doesn't mean to expand and ask SIX DIFFERENT QUESTIONS! Please edit your query again: ask one single question that focuses on one single topic or problem you are experiencing with your worldbuilding. Take a look at the [help] and [tour] for more information on writing good SE questions. This one should be left on hold until improved.